# centos 7 - extend current partition with a new disk

Tags: centos, filesystems, partition, extend

My file system /mysql_database mounted from disk /dev/sdb, partition /dev/sbd1 is 100% filled.
I just added a new disk /dev/sdc from VMWARE and I need to extend the current one. (/dev/sdb1), so my mount point /mysql_database can be extended.

[root@myserver ~]# fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xeccacefd

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    20971519    10484736   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the new disk /dev/sdc. Extend the existing virtual disk backing /dev/sdb, resize its partition, and resize the file system on /dev/sdb1.

Multiple disks is only practical if you are using LVM, or have multiple file systems at different mount points.